# When is EOL for Oracle Linux 8.5

Tags: linux, oracle-linux

I found the EOL information on Oracle site a bit confusing - https://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/elsp-lifetime-069338.pdf
The above link shows EOL for premier support. They offer basic support as well which is less expensive than the premier support. What will the EOL for Oracle Linux 8.5 if no support package is bought from Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

### What will the EOL for Oracle Linux 8.5 if no support package is bought from Oracle?

When offered, Oracle Linux Premier Support, Oracle Linux Basic Support, and Oracle Linux Network Support for
Oracle Linux program releases 5, 6, 7, and 8 will be available for ten years from the date a release of the Oracle
Linux program becomes generally available.

**For all other Oracle Linux program releases, Oracle Linux Premier
Support, Oracle Linux Basic Support, and Oracle Linux Network Support be will be available for eight years from
the date a release of the Oracle Linux program becomes generally available.** If offered, support for Oracle Linux
program releases 5, 6, 7, and 8 may be extended for an additional three years with Oracle Linux Extended Support.

[Oracle Linux and Oracle VM Support Policies](https://www.oracle.com/us/support/library/enterprise-linux-support-policies-069172.pdf)

Effective Date June 4, 2021

Last Update: September 3, 2021

---

---

### Life Cycle

The service lifetime and risk tolerance of the server also needs to be determined. Operating systems and  software upgrades come on a periodic basis, called a release cycle. **Vendors only support older versions of  software for a certain period of time before not offering any updates; this is called a maintenance  cycle or life cycle.**

In an enterprise server environment, maintenance and release cycles are critical considerations because it  is time-consuming and expensive to do major upgrades. Instead, the server hardware itself is often  replaced because increased performance is worth the extra expense, and the resources involved are often  many times more costly than the hardware

Comment: Does this mean the EOL will be eight years from the general availability of the release, if no support package is bought and the end user decides to keep using the open source version of Oracle 8.5?

Comment: Do you mean the kernel updates? What if the RHEL kernel is used instead of UEK ?
What EOL is applicable for open source version?